# will every encrypted password of jasypt would contain "=" at the end?

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

While using [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/), the encrypted passwords contains **= (equal character)** at the end. Is it guaranteed that the encrypted passwords will always have = at the end? 
How/Can we control this behavior?

Foe example: `test` is encrypted to `Nv4nMcuVwsvWVuYD7Av44Q==`

Comment: Show an example of an encrypted password.

Comment: Why do you care? Are you trying to use that property (if it is true) in some way?

Comment: Wild guess: Jasypt's password encryption results in a sequence of bytes which is subsequently base64-encoded, hence the equals sign at the end.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes... To know whether a password is encrypted so that to decrypt it!

Comment: @Ram What if the user has a uncrypted password that ends with `=` then?

Comment: @Kayaman `test` is encrypted into `Nv4nMcuVwsvWVuYD7Av44Q==`

Comment: As Robby said, that is base 64 encoded...

Comment: @Ram And you should be around long enough to understand that you **update** your question when you have more information; instead of putting that into comments.

Comment: @Ram You **never** decrypt passwords. You encrypt user input, and then you check if the result of that matches your stored encrypted password. And of course, you hash things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `=`s come from padding the Base64 representation of the encryption / hash output.

In that case, the answer is generally [no, it won't necessarily end with "="](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding).

However if the algorithm you're using produces constant-length output (e.g. if it uses hashing along the way), it might by a chance end up producing those "="s all the time - but there's no way of knowing that for sure unless you fully understand all steps the algorithm you're using performs.